# Running gearman on a Heroku Worker

Tags: php, heroku, gearman

I have a PHP app running on heroku (cedar stack). I'm at the point where I need to start passing jobs off to workers.

I've looked a both RabbitMQ and gearman. It seems like the best / simplest solution for my app would to use gearman.

So I'm guessing the gearman server would run on the main webapp dyno and then the gearman workerapi would run on separate heroku workers, along with the php code that should do the work.

How can I go about doing this with Heroku?

Thanks

Comment: So, wasn't clear on what you were asking at first.  Then read this: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/background-jobs-queueing  Seems like Cedar provides some structure to facilitate dropping in an external message queue service?  Honestly though I think the code you write to integrate Gearman will not really change much, just a matter of where hooks/triggers happen in the application.  So if you wanted to you could ignore heroku entirely and just focus on existing gearman tutorials.  Maybe someone with more Cedar stack experience can chime in. Or rephrase the question to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Queuing is best done with an addon https://addons.heroku.com/#queues.  The link ( devcenter.heroku.com/articles/background-jobs-queueing ) in the comment to your question by ficuscr should provide you with some insight as to how exactly to implement your workers.